# Do instances of this clone method point back to the original object?

Tags: c++

I'm not a C++ guru, navigating some code from an open source project trying to resolve an issue we have with the Java interface and the documentation is terrible. We've resolved that it may be due to the fact that a cloned object is what is used and not the originally instantiated object. The clone is created in the following method:

```
Base* Computer::Clone() const
{
   Base *clone = new Computer(*this);
   return (clone);
}
```

`Computer` is a subclass of `Base` so it returns a pointer to a `Base` object, created using the constructor of the same class, `Computer` and is done so via dereference (I believe thats what this is called here) with `*this`.

Now assuming `Computer` has an attribute `bool isModeConfigured`, if that is set to `false` for the original object, if the clone sets its to `true` does that replicate through? My inclination here is to say no, given the use of `new`.

Comment: Your inclination is correct -- `new Computer(*this);` is calling the *copy constructor* of the `Computer` class, and is creating a separate/independent `Computer` object that initially has the same settings as `this` Computer but maintains its own independent state thereafter.

Comment: Assuming the copy constructor of the `Computer` class is well defined, this `Clone()` method should make an exact clone of the original object. So, if `isModeConfigured` is set to `false` in original object, cloned object will have the same value. All this obviously assuming copy constructor is correct

Comment: @JeremyFriesner so the copy constructor of `Computer` takes a const-reference as its argument and has an initializer list in which it initializes `isModeConfigured (c.isModeConfigured)`. That initially sets the new object to whatever the reference, in this example the `*this` passed in, is currently set to, but afterwards if changed, doesnt affect the original object?

Comment: @kuro Correct, but my question is about what happens if the clone sets `isModeConfigured` to `true` later; is the original object affected or is it still set to `false`?

Comment: @datta that is correct.

Comment: All the value types will be unaffected. But if you have for example a pointer then just copying the pointer would have the clone point to the same data. With all the problems that would cause. You have to check if there is any shared stated via pointers or references (recursively if there are other classes) but everything else is safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression
`new Computer(*this)` calls the copy constructor `Computer::Computer(const Computer&)`, whatever happens in there depends on its implementation.

Default implementation provided by the compiler (given the requirements for its generation are met) does member-wise copy of all attributes. "copy" means calling copy constructors of all members, same as above.

If you have

```cpp
class Computer{
bool member;
}
```

Then the new instance has a copy of `member` and changing it on one object leaves the other unaffected. Hence both objects are totally independent.

AFAIK all C++ containers have the sane semantics and copies are independent of each other. The problem is with any kind of pointer, since default implementation (even for smart ones) is to make shallow copies. If you had (and you shouldn't) `bool* member`, both objects would share the pointed-to object.

**Note:** Never use `new` (unless you have to but those cases are rare), the modern, safe implementation is

```
std::unique_ptr<Base> Computer::Clone() const
{
   return std::make_unique<Computer>(*this);
}
```